# Wifi Adapter Not Working on ubuntu server, but working on live cd

Tags: networking, server, wireless, usb, d-link

Recently I was attempting to install ubuntu server 16.04.4 (it's a 32-bit system) onto a server. I got the image directly from the ubuntu alternative download section and installed it from a DVD. When I was setting it up, and I attempted to select my USB wifi adapter from the network menu it said that it failed to scan for networks.

After I put in all the information for manual config it told me that it couldn't connect to the network (I tried it many times and I guarantee that the configuration was correct) I decided that I would just continue the install and try to get it setup later. The adapter in question is a D-Link WUA-1340.

This adapter has worked out of the box on both a fresh kali install but also when booting from the live-cd version of Ubuntu Desktop on the same machine.

As I have seen with other questions these are the outputs of different commands

iwconfig

```
virbr0-nic no wireless extensions

wlx0015e9893935 IEEE 802.11bg ESSID:off/any
    Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=0 dBm
    Retry short limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
    Power Managment:on

enp3s4f0 no wireless extensions

enp3s4f1 no wireless extensions

lo no wireless extensions

virbr0 no wireless extensions
```

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 07d1:3c04 D-Link System WUA-1340
```

/etc/network/interfaces - minus comments etc. (i don't want to type it all out)

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I do want to bring attention to the fact that again, the wifi works on the live cd of Ubuntu, and everything works, scanning and all. I also want to point out that it doesn't work at any time when running ubuntu server, that includes during setup

If there is any other information that you need, feel free to ask!

Comment: Boot the Live CD, and in a terminal window, type your `iwconfig` command. It should show you the `driver:` in use. Remember this value. Boot back to normal, and `modprobe` that driver.

Comment: does `sudo iwconfig wlx0015e9893935 txpower auto` have any errors?

Comment: @waltinator when i run iwconfig in the live cd it gives the same output, which has no driver section